# NodeJs JSON.parse - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, json, parsing

Essentially all I am trying to do is simply parse my JSON file using this code:

```
var fileName = `./tasks/file-1.json`

fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, data){

    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(`Entered ${parsedData.fname}`);

});
```

My **file-1.json** file looks like this:

```
{
  "fname": "Test"
}
```

So for whatever reason the console should log "Entered Test", however it is throwing me the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

I have checked over everything and I'm unsure of where to go from here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is that the complete code or just a snippet? Because your code works fine

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal that is the complete code apart from the const fs = require('fs');

Comment: I had the node project running in my local and I tried your code and I got `"Entered Test"` in console

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal it happened sometimes not always. Jamesthoo are you able to figure out it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the encoding of your file.

also try

```
fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data){

    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(`Entered ${parsedData.fname}`);

});
```

Comment: I had two exact (visibly) copies of the same JSON file and one was failing to JSON.parse() ... turned out the one that could not parse was encoded "UTF-8 with BOM" thankfully VSCode showed that in the editor footer after I found this response.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I created a simple example.
File name must be the exact driectory and your JSON file should not include `;`

You can use `__dirname` gives you the current directory path and `path.join` combines the given string parameters to understanble path.

Hope this help.

```
// index.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path= require('path');

const file = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'test.json'));
console.log(JSON.parse(file.toString()).key);
```

```
// test.json
{
    "key": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the JSON file exists in the same path you provided.

This one is working bro!

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fileName = './tasks/file-1.json'

fs.readFile(fileName, function(err, data){
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(`Entered: ${parsedData.fname}`);
});
```